# What is the purpose of <app-control-message> in angular 8 and how it is used?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, controls

I need to create a button for uploading a file in my form. I am using  tag in my html but it is throwing an error : Can't bind to 'control' since it isn't a known property of 'app-contorl-message'.
Here is my html code -

```
  <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input *ngIf="mode == 'CREATE'" type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event)" 
             accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"/>
            <app-contorl-message [control]="form.get('file')"></app-contorl-message>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

here is def of onSelect($event) :

```
onFileSelect(event) {
    this.form.get('file').setValue(event.srcElement.files);
    this.fileData = event.srcElement.files;
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Thanks in advnace!

Comment: you have an spelling error on word `contorl` . that's probably why you're getting the error. also maybe `app-control-message` is defined in your project, and it's not part of angular or any other module. you should find a component with selector: `app-control-message` and check if it has a property called `control`

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppControlMessageComponent` you need to create an `@Input()` named `control`. To learn more about inputs and output, visit: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

**app-control-message.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-app-control-message",
  templateUrl: "./app-control-message.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app-control-message.component.css"]
})
export class AppControlMessageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() control; // Input whose value parent component will provide

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```